# Console only displays 0 for all doubles

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, codeblocks

When I compile my code in Code:Blocks or Eclipse and run it the console displays all double variables as 0.000000.

It happens with even the simplest code like:

```
double a = 1.0;
printf("%lf", a);
```

console shows: 0.000000

This doesn't happen to `int` variables though. Is my compiler set up the wrong way?

Comment: isn't it like `%f` is enough for `double`?

Comment: I tried it with %f, oddly it works. But why doesnt it work with %lf then? O.o

Comment: C89 says that l before f leads to undefined behavior. And C90 probably says the same.

C99 on the other hand says that l before f has no effect

Comment: What version of compiler is it?

Comment: The `printf` format specifier for `double ` is `%f` and a `float` argument is promoted to `double`.

Comment: I have a -std=c11 as a compiler flag, dont know if it works though. My for-loops are working so i guess im using c99 or c11.

Comment: the format '%lf` is for `long double`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%f` to print `double` values, `%lf` is *not required.*

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1,

> `l (ell)`
>
> ... or has no effect on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion
>   specifier.